# Tigase Server have installed on VM but its not starting... what i do?

Tags: xmpp, tigase

I have installed "tigase server" on my VM. when i m starting by using

```
/etc/init.d/tigased start
```

it says :

```
Error: tigased not started
```

from where i would like to view logs related tigase to resolve this problem.
Please suggess

Comment: please some more information i.e. whats is in your log file

Comment: I am also finding logs where i need to go to view logs.